Custom routes per user in Nuxt 3
Let's say, I have 2 user types: admin and client and the following directory structure:
pages/admin/products.vue
pages/admin/settings.vue
pages/client/products.vue


When a user of type admin heads to /products – pages/admin/products.vue is used
When a user of type client heads to /products page – pages/client/products.vue is used
When a user of type admin heads to /settings – pages/admin/settings.vue is used
When a user of type client heads to /settings – 404 not found because there's no pages/client/settings.vue page

In other words, I want each user to have its own routes
How can I approach this? I've played around with router.options.ts. But I can't get an instance of currently authorised user from there to read its type. If I could, there would be no problem to modify routes as needed:
// app/router.options.ts

import type { RouterConfig } from "@nuxt/schema"

export default <RouterConfig>{
  routes(routes) {
    const { user } = useAuthStore() // Error: []: "getActivePinia()" was called but there was no active Pinia. Are you trying to use a store before calling "app.use(pinia)"?
    if (user.type === 'admin') {
      // return admin routes 
    } else {
      // return client routes
    }
  }
}


Have you tried using Middleware? https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/middleware

Have you considered using components and conditional rendering? Here's a working example -
Components structure -
components
├── admin
│   ├── Products.vue
│   └── Settings.vue
└── client
    └── Products.vue

3 directories, 3 files

A straightforward pages/products page is for route /products that leverage components to show conditional Products
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      /* This can be a dynamic value using store or something like that */
      isSuperUser: true,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<template>
  <AdminProducts v-if="isSuperUser" />
  <ClientProducts v-else />
</template>

Page (pages/settings) for route /settings that leverage components to show conditional Settings for admin and redirects to /404 for client -
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      /* This can be a dynamic value using store or something like that */
      isSuperUser: true,
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    if (!this.isSuperUser) {
      this.$router.push("/404");
    }
  },
};
</script>


<template>
  <AdminSettings v-if="isSuperUser" />
</template>

I hope it helps!

A suggestion that might help:

Define generic routes for both of them, rather than having role-based paths at the top level.
pages/products.vue
pages/settings.vue

Create a middleware that would check the user's role before redirection




export default function ({ store, redirect, route }) {
  const user = store.state.auth.user;
  if (!user) {
    // Assuming there's a login page
    return redirect('/login');
  }
  const basePath = route.path.split('/')[1];

  // Redirect if trying to access a role-specific path without proper role
  if (basePath === 'admin' && user.type !== 'admin') {
    return redirect('/404');
  }
  if (basePath === 'client' && user.type !== 'client') {
    return redirect('/404');
  }
}



You can simply apply this middleware globally in nuxt.config.js or in specific pages using the middleware in the component.

Inside your pages(/settings or /products) you can dynamically load the components based on the user's role.



<template>
  <div>
    <component :is="roleSpecificComponent" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    roleSpecificComponent() {
      const user = this.$store.state.auth.user;
      if (!user) {
        return null;
      }
      // Load specific component based on the user type
      if (user.type === 'admin') {
        return () => import(`~/components/admin/${this.$route.name}.vue`);
      } else if (user.type === 'client') {
        return () => import(`~/components/client/${this.$route.name}.vue`);
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
}
</script>



I hope this helps!

Is your store auto imported ? Usually I have to import the pinia store before using it.
Example
import { useAuthStore } from '@/stores/auth'
const store = useAuthStore()

And since were in the nuxt universe I would consider a route middleware here https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/middleware. Within this you can use your store and have conditions to call the navigateTo() https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/navigate-to composable to navigate the user to a 404 page you can use showError https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/show-error
I can imagine that the nuxt need to have all routes at startup since your users usually are authenticated in runtime


I've tried both. I get the same Error: []: "getActivePinia()" was called but there was no active Pinia. Are you trying to use a store before calling "app.use(pinia)"?



I don't see how middleware & navigateTo can be used here.  Say, I'm navigating to /products as admin, I expect /pages/admin/products.vue to open – but I get error right away because /products path doesn't exist



Yes, that's why the way I see it is to tinker with router.options.ts. Routes being initiated at startup also the reason why store is not yet available

